# Java Regex Matches

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have some problems with my code

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
          String Str = new String("adminn, super, supervisor");

          if(Str.matches(".*(admin).*")) {
              System.out.println("here we go");
          }else {
              System.out.println("out");
          }
      
   }
```

This is my code,
The expected result
the output is "**out**" what should be "**here we go again**"
Is there a way to make the values of String str exactly match?

I hope you suggest maybe using regex or anything,

Comment: You missed `\\b` on both ends of the word to match it as a whole word.

Comment: "*The expected result the output is "out"*" why?